# Converting InputStreamCache to POJO

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling, jbossfuse

I'm trying to convert a `JSON` response, which is in `InputStreamCache` format, to POJO in Apache Camel, as follows:

```
<convertBodyTo type="com.temp.MyPojo"/>
```

But, I'm getting following exception:

```
No body available of type: model.so.response.MyResponse but has value: 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@3a689bf8 of type: 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache on: Message: [Body is 
instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]. Caused by: No type converter 
available to convert from type: 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: 
model.so.response.MyResponse with value 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@3a689bf8. 
Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]]. 
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type 
converter available to convert from type: 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: 
model.so.response.MyResponse with value 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@3a689bf8]
```

Is there any way by which I can directly convert `StreamCache` payload to POJO using convertBodyTo component?  I don't want to write an explicit convertor.

---

Note :  I'm aware of `unmarshal` component. I want to confirm whether the same functionality can be achieved using `convertBodyTo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add camel-jackson as dependency as it has the ability to convert from JSon payload to POJOs if you turn it on.

See http://camel.apache.org/json the section *Integrating Jackson with Camel's TypeConverters*

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with maven dependencies.
For Spring boot applications you might use "camel-jackson-starter" instead of "camel-jackson".